# What Star Trek TNG episode involves Troi being assaulted after a betting game of some kind?

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

I vaguely recall watching part of an episode at a young age, that left me with only these impressions:

- Gambling / games…
- Leading someone (Worf?) to lose and become excessively angry…
- Which caused him to physically attack and/or get physical, perhaps by, er, “engaging” someone’s (Troi’s?) breasts…
- But maybe only in a dream?

There may have also been some aspect of repetition, like someone kept repeatedly losing and getting aggressive.

I’m not totally hallucinating this episode, am I?

Comment: Many episodes had gambling (poker) that involved both Worf and Troi, and Worf (nearly?) always did poorly in these games. But I don't recall him ever becoming excessively angry from this (annoyed maybe) or handling anyone's breasts.

Comment: There may have also been some aspect of repetition, like someone kept repeatedly losing and getting aggressive.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Maybe it was [Violations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violations_%28Star_Trek%3a_The_Next_Generation%29) from season 5?

While transporting Ullian telepaths, Troi is telepathically molested. The offender uses a memory she had with Riker cleaning up after a poker game and inserts himself in it, changing the outcome from pleasant to quite unpleasant.

The encounter played out with him pinning Troi to the floor while she begs to be released. During the episode she was forced to experience this a couple times.

Answer (score 5):

Worf bit Troi on the cheek while she was bathing in one episode, but there was no gambling or poker in that episode. Like Erik said, you may be thinking of Violations, but that wasn't Worf.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it wasn't [Cause and effect](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cause_and_Effect_%28episode%29) from TNG season 5?  They get caught in a time loop and keep repeating the same day over and over again.

Comment: This would have been my vote too, for the repetition and poker themes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Liaisons](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Liaisons_%28episode%29) from season 7?